# When a URL has a parameter, why do we place the child component inside an attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, frontend

I am currently watching a tutorial on React.

[image]

1. Why do we place the `<Person />` inside the `children` attribute instead of between the `<Route></Route>`?
2. Why is `<Person />` wrapped between `{}`. I thought that the `{}` inside a jsx expression signals that everything inside of it are javascript expressions. But `<Person />` is not a javascript expression?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Why do we place the `<Person />` inside the children attribute instead of between the `<Route></Route>`?

They are 2 ways of using `children` in react component. I'm not sure why the mentor used both of them. Maybe he/she just showed you 2 ways of using `children`.

> 2. Why is `<Person />` wrapped between {}. I thought that the {} inside a jsx expression signals that everything inside of it are javascript expressions. But  is not a javascript expression?

`Route` has a prop `children` and it receives a function component `Person`, so you should wrap it by `{}`. Read doc [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#children-func).

```js
const Person = () => {
  return <p>Person</p>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" children={<Person />} />

       {/* You can rewrite it as below */}

        <Route exact path="/" children={() => { return <p>Person</p>; }} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-child-vjx0l?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I see that it works via your codesanbox link. However, the fact still remains that `<Person />` is not valid javascript syntax. I thought thought anything inside the `{}` must be nothing more than javascript.

Comment: It is `JSX` syntax. You should read react [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) to understand.